# What's the different between type constructor in Haskell and java generic type?

Tags: java, haskell, generics, monads

I am reading something about monad with no experience in Haskell and confused with the concept of type constructor.

> A monad is a triple (`M`, `unitM`, `bindM`) consisting of a type constructor `M` and a pair of polymorphic functions.
>
> ```
> unitM :: a -> M a
>
> bindM :: M a -> (a -> M b) -> M b
> ```

In Java:

```
public class M<T> {
    static <T> M<T> unit(T a)
    static <T,R> M<R> bind(M<T> a, Function<T,M<R>> f)
}
```

I considered they are the same, type constructor is just something like generic type in Java, am I right? If not, what's the difference?

Comment: in Java the type would be the name of the class

Comment: Well, it would be more akin to an `interface`, or at least an *abstract* class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't sound confused to me. That looks like an unusually accurate translation into Java of Haskell's Monad class.

In Haskell, a "type" is a concrete type with no un-specified parameters, like `Integer`, `M<String>`, or `M<T>` for any fixed `T`. Something with one or more remaining parameters, like just `M`, is a "type constructor", because it is like a constructor for types: it must be given one type argument (a value for `T`) in order to produce a concrete type.